# Python function to write to file doesn't switch to else statement on next call

Tags: python

I have this python function I'm trying to get to save an incremental id to a file.

```
def generate_id():
     with open(".id.txt", "w+") as id:  
         person_id = id.read()
         print('1:', person_id)
         if person_id == '':
             person_id = 1
             id.write(str(person_id))
             print("if", person_id)
             return person_id
         else:
             person_id = int(person_id)
             person_id += 1
             id.truncate()
             id.write(str(person_id))
             print("else", person_id)
             return person_id
```

Problem is, this is the output I get on each call:

```
In [36]: generate_id()
1:
if 1
Out[36]: 1

In [37]: generate_id()
1:
if 1
Out[37]: 1

In [38]: generate_id()
1:
if 1
Out[38]: 1
```

Any ideas on how I could get the value to increment on each call?

---

### EDIT

This is the code I wound up with to solve my problem. Thanks for all the help!

```
def generate_id():
    with open(".id.txt", "a+") as unique_id:  # a+ creates the file if it does not exist 
        unique_id.seek(0)
        person_id = unique_id.read()

        if not person_id:
            person_id = 1
        else:
            person_id = int(person_id)
            person_id += 1

    with open(".id.txt", "w+") as unique_id:
        unique_id.write(str(person_id))

        return person_id
```

Comment: You're calling the function from scratch each time. Why are you doing that, rather than iterating through the file inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
def generate_id():
     with open("myfile.txt", "r+") as id:
         person_id = id.read()
         print('1:', person_id)
         if person_id == '':
             person_id = 1
             id.write(str(person_id))
             print("if", person_id)
             return person_id
         else:
             person_id = int(person_id)
             person_id += 1
             id.seek(0)
             id.truncate()
             id.write(str(person_id))
             print("else", person_id)
             return person_id
```

Replace the `w+` with `r+`. `w+` deletes the file contents even before you read from it, so the file will always be empty. `r+`, on the other hand, appends to the file. In order to delete the contents before writing back, you need to set the pointer of the file object to 0, which explains the `id.seek(0)` (position zero - at the beginning). Then you can write again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation [@wcyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878244/wcyn)! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file.

Since you are opening the file using `w+`, you are always clearing its contents, thus the call to `.read` returns an empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I'll do some refactoring to see if I can get the function  to write to file  an incremented id on each call.

Answer (score 2):

On the first call, you must ensure that the file exists, with

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(".id.txt"):
```

if not, open with `"w+"` else open with `"r+"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator to generate successive `person_id`:

```
def increment_id(start = 1):
    s = str(start)
    while True:
        yield s
        s = str(1 + int(s))
```

Used like:

```
person_id = increment_id()

print(next(person_id)) #prints 1
print(next(person_id)) #prints 2
print(next(person_id)) #prints 3
```

In your code (after you fix some of the other issues that people have pointed out) you could just use

```
id.write(next(person_id))
```

It will automatically write the next value, withour you having to worry about the logic of updating it.